# Yeoman; generator-angularfire says it writes to npm-debug.log

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower, angularfire

I have installed fresh copy of yo generator-angularfire. When I run`grunt` command it throws the following error. However it does open the configured browser with karma results roughly for about 4 seconds and closes triggering the error below.

```
Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\sublime projects\chatApp\app\bower.json' Use --force to continue.
```

The interesting thing is that I do have bower.json file at the directory shown above. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error by modifiying one line in Gruntfile.js which is at the root of the angularfire project.  Line 166 if you haven't modified file yet. Out of the box it will say

```
cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
```

delete template code between the quotes like so `cwd: ' '` and you're good to go. 
Solution came from this [link](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/841) and this [one](https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire/issues/8)